# Cannot resolve symbol 'CommandCapture'

Tags: android, import, root

I'm trying to create a root app and I found out about `RootTools`.

https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools/releases

I went ahead and downloaded the `RootTools.jar`

I followed this guide to import `RootTools.jar`

> In your project, choose File menu > Project Structure (there's a bug
>   in 0.4.4 and this menu item won't have a title at all; it still works)
>
> > Modules > choose your module > Dependencies > + button > File dependency > choose your library from the file picker. That file needs
> >     to be somewhere beneath the root directory of your projet; the libs
> >     directory is fine.

I now put

```
CommandCapture command = new CommandCapture(0, "cp -f " + sourceLocation + " " + targetLocation);
RootTools.getShell(true).add(command);
```

Inside my code, the issue with this is that CommandCapture is highlighted in red and I get an issue saying that this symbol is not resolved

[image: http://i.imgur.com/x2wlu46.png]

This is my whole code so far.

```
package dgameman1.com.emojiupdaterroot;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.stericson.RootTools.RootTools;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // final Spinner emojiSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.emojiSpinner);
        final Button updateEmojiButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateEmojiButton);

        updateEmojiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    CommandCapture command = new CommandCapture(0, "cp -f " + sourceLocation + " " + targetLocation);
                    RootTools.getShell(true).add(command);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `clean-Rebuild-Restart` & Import once again .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya By this you mean, to click Clean Project under File, Then Rebuild, and restart Android Studio?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I went ahead and did that but the error still persists. http://i.imgur.com/x2wlu46.png

Comment: Are you using Gradle as a dependency manager?

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh god, I honestly just started so I'm not sure, but whenever I run the app, I always see gradle doing random stuff in the statusbar below

Comment: @cricket_007 Ah.. Well... That's what I ended up doing lol

Comment: I mean, can you import other classes? Are you sure CommandCapture is actually in that release that you are using? The documentation you looked at for that class could be outdated

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, I went ahead and am able to import other classes. And omg I just found out that the downloadable .jar doesn't have everything. Maybe CommandCapture is one of those things? I'm told to build it from this source https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools , except I have no idea how =/

Comment: It's java source code. You download it and open it as a regular java project, though you probably don't need to do that, just the release that you are using has some other way to do what you want or you are missing some other jar file as a library dependency

Comment: Yeah, I just used the one straight from the github and the same issue happened. Any ideas =/? @cricket_007

Comment: Sorry, haven't used the library and not at a development environment to test it. You can try reading or making an issue in github for the repository. I looked at the first page and it said something similar to your question

Comment: @cricket_007 Ah, Yeah I will =] Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

The library went through a massive code re organization and while it is now cleaner this means a few things have changed. For instance, the library' kernel is found under `RootShell`, meaning that the newly renamed `Command` class belongs to `com.stericson.rootshell.execution`